# Website needs to only be accessible from two specific iPad's and no other devices or IP's (PHP)

Tags: php, security, ipad, .htaccess

The business I work for has a website for employees to clock in and out of their work shifts.

This website needs to be only accessible from our two in-house iPads. I tried doing a simple .htaccess password protection to the directory, but every time the browser is closed (which is often), we need to re-input the password.

I thought about limiting access to the iPads' IP addresses (also with .htaccess), but they have dynamic IP's so that doesn't work either.

What other solutions are there? Is there a way to make a website device-specific regardless of IP? A way to somehow "catch" the range of an iPad's dynamic IP's?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can't you simply store the user credentials in the browser of your iPads? Any decent browser can do that nowadays.

Comment: I tried the normal password protection method with .htaccess and was prompted every time I closed the browser to re-enter credentials, so it isn't storing credentials automatically. Is there a way to store them manually using mobile Safari?

Answer (score 1):

You could do logins using cookies and sessions like most other sites. This would allow you to persist the login through browser shutdowns.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, Reese. I know some basics of PHP but I don't know too much about cookies or sessions. Do you have a link to a tutorial that could help me? I was hoping I could do this through .htaccess somehow! Seems the simplest/most secure.

Comment: [This](http://devzone.zend.com/article/646) is fairly old, but it still should serve as an excellent primer to using cookies and sessions.

Comment: It seems like sessions and cookies don't last forever. Is there perhaps a simpler way to do this?

Comment: You hardly need forever. A cookie set 20 years in the future will far outlast your needs. Even then, you can save the login credentials in the browser.

Comment: Check this link for storing passwords on iPad safari browser: http://www.padgadget.com/2014/04/14/padgadgets-ipad-tips-how-to-save-passwords-on-your-ipad-using-icloud-keychain/